# Character sinks into ground when switching animations

Tags: unity, animation, character

I originally posted this question on the unity forums, but no one answered my question.
Here it is:

Hello, I have been game developing since May and today I finally figured out how animations work in unity!
But as with everything new in developing, I have problems. Let me just be straight with you. I have absolutely no idea what just happened.
I have a gif you what happens. Why does the character sink like that? Here is my gif and animation image [image: Capt.gif upload_2020-10-12_22-7-37.png]

[image]

[image]

I don't have any scripts or parameters for testing purposes. I just let it switch automatically. Here are my options for the transition:

[image]

Comment: Is the root or hip bone at a different location in the running clip than the walking clip, in your animation source file(s)?

Comment: I don't know... They are the exact same models from mixamo
https://www.mixamo.com/#/?page=1&query=ninja&type=Character

Comment: Are you sure that that is the running animation? Your ninja on mixamo has his arms backwards on the running animation, yours looks like it's typing on a keyboard

Comment: Yes. This same thing has happened to me on another project which had another animation and character.

Comment: Welcome. I couldn't download the model as its ask for account (maybe later). But I say to import the model in Blender and look at it, maybe tune animations, move bones, etc. Note: I'm assuming the model comes in a format that can be imported in Blender, or that importer addons exist and are relatively easy to find and install.

Answer (score 2):

Just change rig of the animation to humanoid from generic

Comment: You should probably tell them how to do this: where is this option located?